# How to implement a parallel jobs and queues system

Tags: powershell, csv, parallel-processing

I spent days trying to implement a parallel jobs and queues system, but... I tried but I can't make it. Here is the code without implementing nothing, and CSV example from where looks.

I'm sure this post can help other users in their projects.

Each user have his pc, so the CSV file look like:

```
pc1,user1
pc2,user2
pc800,user800
```

CODE:

```
#Source File:
$inputCSV = '~\desktop\report.csv'
$csv = import-csv $inputCSV -Header PCName, User
echo $csv #debug

#Output File:
$report = "~\desktop\output.csv"

#---------------------------------------------------------------

#Define search:
$findSize = 40GB
Write-Host "Lonking for $findSize GB sized Outlook files"

#count issues:
$issues = 0 

#---------------------------------------------------------------

foreach($item in $csv){

    if (Test-Connection -Quiet -count 1 -computer $($item.PCname)){

        $w7path = "\\$($item.PCname)\c$\users\$($item.User)\appdata\Local\microsoft\outlook"

        $xpPath = "\\$($item.PCname)\c$\Documents and Settings\$($item.User)\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook"

            if(Test-Path $W7path){

                if(Get-ChildItem $w7path -Recurse -force -Include *.ost -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt $findSize}){

                    $newLine =  "{0},{1},{2}" -f $($item.PCname),$($item.User),$w7path
                    $newLine |  add-content $report

                    $issues ++
                    Write-Host "Issue detected" #debug
                    }
            }

            elseif(Test-Path $xpPath){

                if(Get-ChildItem $w7path -Recurse -force -Include *.ost -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt $findSize}){

                    $newLine =  "{0},{1},{2}" -f $($item.PCname),$($item.User),$xpPath
                    $newLine |  add-content $report

                    $issues ++
                    Write-Host "Issue detected" #debug
                    }
            }

            else{
                write-host "Error! - bad path"
            }
    }

    else{
        write-host "Error! - no ping"
    }
}

Write-Host "All done! detected $issues issues"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel data processing in PowerShell is not quite simple, especially with
queueing. Try to use some existing tools which have this already done.
You may take look at the module
[SplitPipeline](https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline). The cmdlet
`Split-Pipeline` is designed for parallel input data processing and supports
queueing of input (see the parameter `Load`). For example, for 4 parallel
pipelines with 10 input items each at a time the code will look like this:

```
$csv | Split-Pipeline -Count 4 -Load 10, 10 {process{
    <operate on input item $_>
}} | Out-File $outputReport
```

All you have to do is to implement the code `<operate on input item $_>`.
Parallel processing and queueing is done by this command.

---

UPDATE for the updated question code. Here is the prototype code with some
remarks. They are important. Doing work in parallel is not the same as
directly, there are some rules to follow.

```
$csv | Split-Pipeline -Count 4 -Load 10, 10 -Variable findSize {process{
    # Tips
    # - Operate on input object $_, i.e $_.PCname and $_.User
    # - Use imported variable $findSize
    # - Do not use Write-Host, use (for now) Write-Warning
    # - Do not count issues (for now). This is possible but make it working
    # without this at first.
    # - Do not write data to a file, from several parallel pipelines this
    # is not so trivial, just output data, they will be piped further to
    # the log file
    ...
}} | Set-Content $report
# output from all jobs is joined and written to the report file
```

---

UPDATE: How to write progress information

> SplitPipeline handled pretty well a 800 targets csv, amazing. Is there anyway
>   to let the user know if the script is alive...? Scan a big csv can take about
>   20 mins. Something like "in progress 25%","50%","75%"...

There are several options. The simplest is just to invoke `Split-Pipeline` with
the switch `-Verbose`. So you will get verbose messages about the progress and
see that the script is alive.

Another simple option is to write and watch verbose messages from the jobs,
e.g. `Write-Verbose ... -Verbose` which will write messages even if
`Split-Pipeline` is invoked without `Verbose`.

And another option is to use proper progress messages with `Write-Progress`.
See the scripts:

- [Test-ProgressJobs.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline/blob/master/Tests/Test-ProgressJobs.ps1)
- [Test-ProgressTotal.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline/blob/master/Tests/Test-ProgressTotal.ps1)

`Test-ProgressTotal.ps1` also shows how to use a collector updated from jobs
concurrently. You can use the similar technique for counting issues (the
original question code does this). When all is done show the total number of
issues to a user.

Comment: I misunderstanding something, I change `<operate $_>` by my code `start-job $sb -argumentlist...` , but I got this error: Split-Pipeline : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ScriptBlock' because it is null.

Comment: You should not use `start-job` in you code. "Jobs" are created for you by `Split-Pipeline`. In other words, you should replace `<operate $_>` with slightly adjusted `$sb` (add `process` block, do not use parameters, data come from pipeline).

Comment: I tried `$csv | Split-Pipeline  -Count 4 -Load 10, 10 {process{ $sb` but didn't, tried some newbie changes but no luck...

Comment: Ask a question about the problem. What is the error message, if any, or what is not working?

Comment: See the UPDATE section in the answer. Start with some trivial code and minimum of input. Also, use `Split-Pipeline -Verbose` to see some stats.

Comment: Thanks, now is working. What means the 2nd ",10" in "-Load 10,10" ? I read the help command but I'm not sure. ¿For 50 jobs at time I should type 50,50 ? is correct?

Comment: No, for 50 jobs at a time you use `Count 50`. Do not do that, it's too much. `Load` defines part sizes, minimum and maximum, i.e. number of items per job. If you want 10 items per job exactly then use `Load 10,10`.

Comment: splitpipeline handled pretty well a 800 targets csv, amazing. Is there anyway to let the user know if the script is alive...? scan a big csv can take about 20 mins. Something like "in progress 25%","50%","75%"... ?

Comment: a part of Warning I mean.

Comment: See another UPDATE section. BTW, as far as it works for you fine, you may accept the answer. I am glad that the tool helped to solve you task.

Comment: How I should use Splitpipeline stored on a shared server, tried to `import-module \\server\splitpipeline` but can't be loaded.

Comment: May be the way is in the same script, copy the folder Splitpipeline to host pc from the server, then do a Join-Path and then the import-module? is this fine?

Comment: Ask another question. It is about loading *any* module in this way, not `SplitPipeline`, in particular. This topic is over, IMHO. SO comments are not for chatting, really.