# Check if file exists from URL powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following line of code to download a list of files from a text file. It is part of a larger program. Currently, the PS script will grab the files that were downloaded. But if a file does not exist, I would like to pause the PS script so the user can adjust the URL to point a good file, then continue. Is this possible? If not maybe go through the list and output which paths are bad?

```
Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest $_ -OutFile C:\test\download\$(Split-Path $_ -Leaf)}
```

**Edit**

I will test out the -method HEAD but for now, I found the test-path cmdlet. Still working out the kinks to not display the whole path but this seems to work for me. As it prints out what is found and missing. I will have to work on adding a pause and re run in my program.

```
Get-Content c:\file.txt | `Select-Object @{Name='FileName';Expression=$_}},@{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ Test-Path $_}}
```

Comment: canonical way would be to issue a HEAD request for that file, and see what http status code comes back. 404 = no such file.

Comment: Yep, add `-method HEAD` and check urls in multiple (8-64) parallel jobs (see [How to implement a parallel jobs and queues system](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24473550))